# Aligning Elements to have equal height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not too fluent in javascript, so I can't really find any solutions that work for me. I'm trying to align these two elements/divs: the image and the "everything" div to have equal heights, so that my footer fits in. None of the solutions seem to be working. You don't need to pay attention to much of the text or anything. All I need is a solution in how to keep the height of the image the same as the "everything" div. In doing so, I would want the "everything" div not to be sstatic, so it can change according to browser size using the em font values and percentage width/height values. So, basically, the image height should be equal to the "everything" div height without changing the hight of the "everything" div as it would be without the added code. Here is the code :

```css
html {
  margin: 0 0;
}

.kewlimage {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 45.4em;
}

.everything {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-size: 1.55em;
  padding: 0.3475em 0.45em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightslategrey;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: auto 6%;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 1.55em;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: lightslategrey;
  padding: 0.3475em 0.45em;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkslategrey;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0.7em;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.everything {
  background-image: url("https://wallpaper.wiki/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/wallpaper.wiki-Backgrounds-Flat-Design-HD-PIC-WPB004634.jpg");
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: ghostwhite;
  font-family: "comic sans ms";
  font-size: 3.25em;
  margin: 4% 0% 5% 5%;
}

.title {}

h2.subtitle {
  color: white;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 2.5% auto;
}

.database-explanation {
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
  background-color: rgba(95, 158, 160, 0.3);
  width: 87.5%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 9% auto;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 3.5% auto;
}

.stand-for {
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
  background-color: rgba(95, 158, 160, 0.3);
  width: 87.5%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 8% auto;
}

.footertop {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#divider {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4% auto;
  width: 90%;
  border: 0.1em solid rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="kewlimage" src="https://alorica.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/jason-nguyen-treelr.jpg">
</div>
<div class="everything">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="news.html">News</a>
    <a href="join-the-team.html">Join the Team</a>
    <a href="archives.html">Archives</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">InterTutor</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="coding.html">Coding</a>
        <a href="science.html">Science</a>
        <a href="math.html">Math</a>
        <a href="history.html">History</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="introduction">
    <h1 class="title">Welcome to Databases</h1>
    <div class="database-explanation">
      <h2 class="subtitle" id="sub1">What is Databases?</h2>
      <p class="text" id="text1">Databases is a website meant for students and adults likewise. Our goal is to have a community of students and adults who can help each other while also learning about what ever they choose though the InterTutor program. We also hope to have a sort
        of archives available for easy to access information. We hope that you use these reponsibly, as we will not be responsible for any innapropriate use of these sources. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="stand-for">
      <h2 class="subtitle">What We Stand For</h2>
      <p class="text">In Databases, we want students to learn, and our name stands as a representation of this. D for diligence, A for ambitious, T for technological, A for approachable, B for benevolent, A for attentive, S for studious, E for efficent, and S for scintillating.
        We hope that all of the people that visit this website stand by the same standards. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footertop">
    <hr id="divider">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code IN the question please

Comment: You may be interested in http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: the code keeps on showing formatting errors, even though when I run it, it still works. So I can't post the question with my formatting

Comment: Then we can't help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: oh there I figured it out here try the code now

Comment: CSS Flexbox with `stretch` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged javascript, here is one js solution:

```
 <script>

img=document.getElementsByClassName('kewlimage')[0];
every=document.getElementsByClassName('everything')[0];
img.style.height=every.offsetHeight+'px'; 

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
 img.style.height=every.offsetHeight+'px';
});  

  </script>
```

Place this code at the bottom of your page, before closing of `body` tag. Script simple calculates height of *everything* div, and apply it to image.

**However**, nowadays, you can easily get equal blocks/columns heights, *using only CSS methods*, and by slightly changing your html structure. However, this should work, without modifying anything in your current html/css.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check out this [very helpful website](http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/) to avoid giving other people eye cancer when they visit your website :-)

Then wrap your content in a holder div, I gave it the class `.fullbackground`. This class receives a background image with the `background-size: 50% cover`, which means it will always be 50% of the div's with and will resize to cover the full height. As you don't have a DOM element for the image anymore, you don't need floating, so you can just give `.everything` a width and margin of 50%.

Here's the same thing in a minimal version:

```css
.fullbackground {
    background-image: url(https://alorica.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/jason-nguyen-treelr.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% cover;
}
.everything {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullbackground">
<div class="everything">
    <p>start of content</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>end of content</p>
</div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

And here is your adapted code:

```css
html {
  margin: 0 0;
}

.fullbackground {
    background-image: url(https://alorica.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/jason-nguyen-treelr.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% cover;
}

.everything {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  font-size: 1.55em;
  padding: 0.3475em 0.45em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightslategrey;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: auto 6%;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 1.55em;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: lightslategrey;
  padding: 0.3475em 0.45em;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkslategrey;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0.7em;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.everything {
  background-image: url("https://wallpaper.wiki/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/wallpaper.wiki-Backgrounds-Flat-Design-HD-PIC-WPB004634.jpg");
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: ghostwhite;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 3.25em;
  margin: 4% 0% 5% 5%;
}

.title {}

h2.subtitle {
  color: white;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 2.5% auto;
}

.database-explanation {
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
  background-color: rgba(95, 158, 160, 0.3);
  width: 87.5%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 9% auto;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 3.5% auto;
}

.stand-for {
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
  background-color: rgba(95, 158, 160, 0.3);
  width: 87.5%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 8% auto;
}

.footertop {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#divider {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4% auto;
  width: 90%;
  border: 0.1em solid rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="fullbackground">
    <div class="everything">
      <div class="navbar">
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a href="news.html">News</a>
        <a href="join-the-team.html">Join the Team</a>
        <a href="archives.html">Archives</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">InterTutor</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="coding.html">Coding</a>
            <a href="science.html">Science</a>
            <a href="math.html">Math</a>
            <a href="history.html">History</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="introduction">
        <h1 class="title">Welcome to Databases</h1>
        <div class="database-explanation">
          <h2 class="subtitle" id="sub1">What is Databases?</h2>
          <p class="text" id="text1">Databases is a website meant for students and adults likewise. Our goal is to have a community of students and adults who can help each other while also learning about what ever they choose though the InterTutor program. We also hope to have a sort
            of archives available for easy to access information. We hope that you use these reponsibly, as we will not be responsible for any innapropriate use of these sources. </p>
<p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="stand-for">
          <h2 class="subtitle">What We Stand For</h2>
          <p class="text">In Databases, we want students to learn, and our name stands as a representation of this. D for diligence, A for ambitious, T for technological, A for approachable, B for benevolent, A for attentive, S for studious, E for efficent, and S for scintillating.
            We hope that all of the people that visit this website stand by the same standards. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footertop">
    <hr id="divider">
  </div>
</div>
```